# GAE Django Table Records Pagination?

Tags: css, django, google-app-engine, templates

Anyone have sugestion or example on how displaying Google Datastore records table with pagination on Google App Engine django template? Something like Gmail pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page probably answers your question: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/paging.html

Comment: Thanks Dar, i will try this example

Answer (score 2):

i wrote this class today :)

```
class gaePaginator ():
    leftPages           = 3
    rightPages          = 3
    centerPages         = 1
    totalPages          = 1
    baseURL             = 'http://example.com/%s/'
    moveLeft            = '&lt;'
    moveLeftmax         = '&lt;&lt;'
    moveRight           = '&gt;'
    moveRightmax        = '&gt;&gt;'
    href                = '<a href="%s">%s</a>'
    currentPageWrap     = '<b>%s</b>'
    textBetween         = '...'
    separator           = ' '
    currentPage         = 1


    """
    Ranges for current page
    """
    def leftRange(self):
        return range(1, self.leftPages+1)
    def rightRange(self):
        return range (self.totalPages - self.rightPages+1, self.totalPages + 1)
    def centerRange(self):
        return range(self.currentPage - self.centerPages, self.currentPage + self.centerPages + 1)

    def renderLeftNav(self):
        """
        Method render left page nav tab like <<(move to first page) <(move to previous page).
        """
        result = []
        if self.currentPage <= 1  or self.currentPage > self.totalPages:
            # draw nothing
            pass
        elif self.currentPage == 2:
            #draw only arrow for previous page
            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % 1, self.moveLeft)
            result.append(arrow)
        else:
            #draw arrow for previous page and first page
            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % 1, self.moveLeftmax)
            result.append(arrow)
            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % (self.currentPage - 1), self.moveLeft)
            result.append(arrow)
        return self.separator.join(result)

    def renderRightNav(self):
        """
        Method render left page nav tab like "<<(move to first page) <(move to previous page)"
        """
        result = []
        if self.currentPage >= self.totalPages or self.currentPage < 1:
            #draw nothing
            pass
        elif self.currentPage == self.totalPages - 1:
            #draw only arrow for next page
            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % self.totalPages, self.moveRight)
            result.append(arrow)
        else:
            #draw arrow for next page and for last page
            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % (self.currentPage + 1), self.moveRight)
            result.append(arrow)

            arrow = self.href % (self.baseURL % self.totalPages, self.moveRightmax)
            result.append(arrow)
        return self.separator.join(result)

    def getRange (self):
        result = []
        for i in range(1, self.totalPages+1):
            if i in self.leftRange() or i in self.rightRange() or i in self.centerRange():
                result.append(i)
            else:
                if result[-1] is not None:
                    result.append(None)
        return result

    def renderPageRange (self):
        '''
        Method returns list of pages as urls in HTML representation.
        '''
        result = []
        for i in self.getRange():
            if i == self.currentPage:
                tmp = self.currentPageWrap % i
            else:
                if i is None:
                    tmp = self.textBetween
                else:
                    tmp = self.href % (self.baseURL % i, i)
            result.append(tmp)
        return self.separator.join(result)

    def asURL(self):
        '''
        Method returns list of pages as urls in HTML representation with border arrows.
        '''
        result = []
        result.append(self.renderLeftNav())
        result.append(self.renderPageRange())
        result.append(self.renderRightNav())
        return self.separator.join(result)
```

Using in views.py:

> ```
> from ....main.paginator import gaePaginator
> ```

```
pages = gaePaginator ()
pages.currentPage   = pagesNumber
pages.leftPages     = 2 
pages.rightPages    = 2
pages.centerPages   = 1
pages.totalPages    = totalPagesNumber
pages.baseURL       = 'page/%s'
pages.separator     = '&nbsp;&nbsp;'
result = {'pages'         : pages.asURL(),}
```

using in template:

```
{{ pages }}
```

as result you`ll recieve:
for ten pages,

current page is 1 :  **1**  2  ...  9  10  >  >>

current page is 4 : <<  <  1  2  3  **4**  5  ...  9  10  >  >>

current page is 6 : <<  <  1  2  ...  5  **6**  7  ...  9  10  >  >>

current page is 10: <<  <  1  2  ...  9  **10**

```
<< - moves to first page
< - moves to previous page
> - moves to next page
>> - move to last page
```

also, this code tries to draw pages for any case: for example, if user will set page number = -1 or 100000 "1  2  ...  9  10" will be rendered.

also it can be used in template like django Paginator, but i did not tried to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for simple pagination in Google App Engine try:

http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/simple-pagination-djangocorepaginator/

Comment: Here is the django link, has some great examples: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/